# Structured data and HTML Tables

Tags: html, seo, semantic-markup

I'm building a HTML table that need to be SEO and Google structured data friendly.
See here for my example:

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr role="row">
      <th>Brand</th>
      <th>Car</th>
      <th>Price (USD)</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr role="row">
      <td data-th="Brand">
        Mercedes
      </td>
      <td data-th="Car">
        Mercedes-Benz Maybach Exelero
      </td>
      <td data-th="Price (USD)">
        $8,000,000
      </td>
    </tr>
  <tr role="row">
      <td data-th="Brand">
        Lamborghini
      </td>
      <td data-th="Car">
        Lamborghini Veneno Roadster
      </td>
      <td data-th="Price (USD)">
        $4,500,000
      </td>
    </tr>
  <tr role="row">
      <td data-th="Brand">
        Lykan
      </td>
      <td data-th="Car">
        Lykan Hypersport
      </td>
      <td data-th="Price (USD)">
        $3,400,000
      </td>
    </tr>
  <tr role="row">
      <td data-th="Brand">
        Ferrari
      </td>
      <td data-th="Car">
        2015 Ferrari FXX K
      </td>
      <td data-th="Price (USD)">
        $3,100,000
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Is there any other way to make a Google structured data table? Not with the table structure but using div's and adding the right structured data into it?

Comment: I think using tables might be the best way. Google already shows rich snippets based on tables on a page. And there is no formal equivalent way to do it in schema.org etc. You could back it up with an ItemList that contains all the entities in the table. You could probably do it inline with microdata, or separately with json-ld.

Comment: "Is there any other way to make a Google structured data table?" — You appear to have tabular data. A table appears to be the correct way to mark it up. What problem are you looking to solve by using something else?

Answer (score 3):

Try this instead of table td.

```css
  .table{
    display:table;
  }
  .table-row{
    display: table-row;
  }
  .table-row div{
    display: table-cell;
  }
```

```html
<div class="table"> 
      <div role="row" class="table-row">
        <div>Brand</div>
        <div>Car</div>
        <div>Price (USD)</div>
      </div>
      <div role="row" class="table-row">
        <div data-div="Brand">
          Mercedes
        </div>
        <div data-div="Car">
          Mercedes-Benz Maybach Exelero
        </div>
        <div data-div="Price (USD)">
          $8,000,000
        </div>
      </div>
      <div role="row" class="table-row">
        <div data-div="Brand">
          Lamborghini
        </div>
        <div data-div="Car">
          Lamborghini Veneno Roadster
        </div>
        <div data-div="Price (USD)">
          $4,500,000
        </div>
      </div>
      <div role="row" class="table-row">
        <div data-div="Brand">
          Lykan
        </div>
        <div data-div="Car">
          Lykan Hypersport
        </div>
        <div data-div="Price (USD)">
          $3,400,000
        </div>
      </div>
      <div role="row" class="table-row">
        <div data-div="Brand">
          Ferrari
        </div>
        <div data-div="Car">
          2015 Ferrari FXX K
        </div>
        <div data-div="Price (USD)">
          $3,100,000
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```